# Gridview - Adding of column

Tags: c#, gridview

My question is: Can I add in new column(S) in the gridview if the column is not found in the database?
  - E.g. An indicator if a certain lecturer is a ML/Lec (roles).

I have a gridview that is "extracted" out from the database.
But I want to add in a new row which is not in the database but links to the data in the database.
For example, in the database, I know that a certain lecturer is a module leader, staff.
But I want to have an extra column which can indicate in itself (probably a tick/mark) that the following name (prev column) is a module leader or staff; and i am not allowed to add new column in the database.

Any help appreciated.
Need me to further explain my queries, let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're really looking for is a way to add columns to a gridview when autogeneratecolumns=true..

[Any way to manipulate the columns in GridView with AutoGenerateColumns = true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686544/any-way-to-manipulate-the-columns-in-gridview-with-autogeneratecolumns-true)

Comment: Hello madcolor,
erm not really. my autogeneratecolumns is set to false. 

Husna

Answer (score 0):

Could you not add a column to the dataset that comes from the database, rather than the actual table.  Then fill it with the calculated vaule.